# How to preform insert into BigQuery table of list of values using dbapi

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-db-api

I have a question regarding performing insert into a table in BigQuery using the DBAPI .

The simple insert of 1 value I was able to preform , my question is how to preform insert of list of values.

I couldn't find an example on how to do it, I want to preform something like :

```
query ="insert into test.test values (%s)"
self._cursor.execute(query,(('4'),('3')))
```

But I am getting an error

Thanks,

Nir

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command [`executemany`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#:%7E:text=The%20only%20other%20method%20you%20are%20very%20likely%20to%20use%20is%20when%20you%20have%20to%20do%20a%20multi-row%20insert%3A). This method is used to [insert multiple rows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) in a single operation.

Your code should look something like:

```
query ="insert into test.test values (%s)" 
self._cursor.executemany(query,[('4'),('3')])
```

Also what is the error that you are getting?